# use own logic expression in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I got an expression parsed with pyparsing to reconstruct it as a sort of boolean tree:

```
expr = '(A and B) or C'
parsed -> OR_:[AND_:['A', 'B'] , 'C']
```

A, B and C are keys in a dict with string values (no boolean values!)

OR_ (union) and AND_ (intersection) are only class names and don't do anything rn, I'm thinking of putting an evaluator inside those classes.

now my question is, how do I turn this parsed expression into one that Python can evaluate?
What I'm trying to do is either take some string value and see if it meets the conditions of the whole expression or have it iterate over every subexpression and appending it to a result list.

Example:

```
dict: {'A': ['Hi', 'No', 'Yes'], 'B': ['Why', 'No', 'Okay'], 'C': ['Okay']}
expression = '(A and B) or C'
if value in expression:
 output.append(value)
output -> ['No', 'Okay']  #intersection of A and B, union of that with C
```

It's something like that, but the part `if value in expression` is what bothers me because I can't think of any other way to write it.

Comment: I think you should make the dict values actual sets first, for example: `'A': {'Hi', 'No', 'Yes'}`. Then write code to take your parsed expression `OR_:[AND_:['A', 'B'] , 'C']` and evaluate this, using a stack and the traditional Python set operations where, for example, `AND_:['A', 'B']` evaluates to `dict['A'].intersection(dict['B'])` or simply `dict['A'] & dict['B']`. Similar for union.

Comment: Is this something specific to using `pyparsing`?  I'm not sure exactly what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: @jarmond ahaa i see, this does go into the direction I'm thinking of.
I'm just a bit confused on how to iterate this multiple times in combination with union and exclusion ...

Comment: @KyleParsons uhh I wouldn't say it's specific to pyparsing, but pyparsing helps in parsing the expressions I guess. It diesn't have to be pyparsing, but it's the only parser that I could think of.
my aim is to input any expression with and/or/not and based on that it should output all values that are valid for the expression

Answer (score 1):

We can parse and translate our expression using the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html) module.  We first parse our statement and then define a node transformer that swaps `and` with `&`, `or` with `|`, and wraps variable names in the `set` function.  We can then compile this translated ast and evaluate it in the context of our dictionary.

```
import ast
from typing import Dict, Hashable, List, NoReturn, TypeVar

A = TypeVar('A', bound=Hashable)


def evaluate_logic(expr: str, context: Dict[str, List[A]]) -> List[A]:
    tr = ast.parse(expr, mode='eval')
    new_tr = ast.fix_missing_locations(TranslateLogic().visit(tr))
    co = compile(new_tr, filename='', mode='eval')
    return list(eval(co, context))


class TranslateLogic(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_BoolOp(self, node: ast.BoolOp) -> ast.BinOp:
        op = node.op
        new_op = ast.BitAnd() if isinstance(op, ast.And) else ast.BitOr()
        return nested_op(new_op, [self.visit(value) for value in node.values])

    def visit_Name(self, node: ast.Name) -> ast.Call:
        return call_set(node)

    def visit_Expression(self, node: ast.Expression) -> ast.Expression:
        return super().generic_visit(node)

    def generic_visit(self, node: ast.AST) -> NoReturn:
        raise ValueError(f"cannote visit node: {node}")


def nested_op(op, values: List[ast.AST]) -> ast.BinOp:
    if len(values) < 2:
        raise ValueError(f"tried to nest operator with fewer than two values")
    elif len(values) == 2:
        left, right = values
        return ast.BinOp(left=left, op=op, right=right)
    else:
        left, *rest = values
        return ast.BinOp(left=left, op=op, right=nested_op(op, rest))


def call_set(node: ast.Name) -> ast.Call:
    return ast.Call(func=ast.Name(id='set', ctx=node.ctx), args=[node], keywords=[])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    expr = '(A and B) or C'
    context = {'A': ['Hi', 'No', 'Yes'], 'B': ['Why', 'No', 'Okay'], 'C': ['Okay']}

    print(evaluate_logic(expr, context))
    # prints ['No', 'Okay']
```

I would say that this demonstrates the challenge with generic parsing in Python and then applying custom logic in Python even when leveraging existing parsing libraries.

A few notes.  We're eventually evaluating the code that the user provides.  There's some safety because `generic_visit` *should* raise an error if the user supplies something more complex than just `and`s and `or`s but I would be very wary of this code in a production situation.

Second, there's a bit of complication when translating `and` to `&` (and `or` to `|`) because of how Python represents a chain of `and`s vs a chain of `&`s.  A chain of `and`s become a single `BoolOp` node with multiple values, whereas a chain of `&` become nested `BinOp`s each with a left and a right. Compare

```
ast.dump(ast.parse('A and B and C', mode='eval'))
# "Expression(body=BoolOp(op=And(), values=[Name(id='A', ctx=Load()), Name(id='B', ctx=Load()), Name(id='C', ctx=Load())]))"
```

to

```
ast.dump(ast.parse('A & B & C', mode='eval'))
# "Expression(body=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Name(id='A', ctx=Load()), op=BitAnd(), right=Name(id='B', ctx=Load())), op=BitAnd(), right=Name(id='C', ctx=Load())))"
```

This explains why we need the `nested_op` helper function.

Finally, without more information, we can't implement `not`.  The reason is we haven't defined a "universe of discourse".  In particular, what should `not A` evaluate to?  There are two possible solutions I see:

1. Add an additional argument for specifying the universe of discourse.  Add a `visit_UnaryOp` to translate `not A` into something like `set(U) - set(A)` where `U` is the universe of discourse.
2. Treat `not` like the set difference binary operator.  In this case it would probably be easiest to preprocess the expression as a string to replace `" not "` with `" - "`.

With all this being said, you'll likely save yourself a lot of trouble, though, if you just force your users into a easier to work with (for you) interface.  Something like

```
from my_module import And, Or

expr = Or(And("A", "B"), "C")
context = {'A': ['Hi', 'No', 'Yes'], 'B': ['Why', 'No', 'Okay'], 'C': ['Okay']}

evaluate_logic(expr, context)
```

You force your users to pre-parse the expression they give you but you save yourself a lot of worry and trouble.

Comment: Thanks for ur solution! I'm still trying to understand the code, but it does accomplish what i want with And and Or. Since it doesn't use pyparsing at all, I gotta see if I can just dispose of that inital idea, but still, I'm very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary operators if you convert it into sets:

```py
output = list(set(a) & set(b) | set(c))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but I'm looking for sth more flexible as the expression is dependent on user input so the expression could be any combination with and/or/not

Comment: I think the semantics of `not` are undefined unless we're in some universe of possibilities that we define somewhere.  What should `'not A'`  evaluate to?

Comment: @KyleParsons `not A` should result in basically all elements other than those in A

Comment: Sure but in what context?  If `A = ['Ok', 'No']` then is `not A == ['', 'a', 'b', ..., 'aa', 'ab', ...] # every string but 'Ok' and 'No'` or is the universe of possibilities implicitly assumed to be the union of all the values in your dictionary?

Comment: @KyleParsons Oh sorry i just noticed that I missed to mention sth, there's another list containing all elements from the other lists. Basically `not A` in this case would be comparing ALL to A and result in `['Why', 'Okay']` (not including elements from A, but every other one).  Hope that makes more sense :)